# Appending "pointer to a child class" into a vector of "pointer to the parent class"

Tags: c++, vector, polymorphism, abstraction, static-cast

I am having some difficulties with static casting my child classes into the parent classes using the insert function for "std::vector::insert"

Here is some code to sense of what Im trying to do:

```
  mInstancedObjects.insert(mInstancedObjects.end(), mGates.begin(), mGates.end());
  mInstancedObjects.insert(mInstancedObjects.end(), mProjectiles.begin(), mProjectiles.end());
  mInstancedObjects.insert(mInstancedObjects.end(), mSwitches.begin(), mSwitches.end());
  mInstancedObjects.insert(mInstancedObjects.end(), mPitfalls.begin(), mPitfalls.end());
```

In this case, the vector: `mInstancedObjects` is a vector of pointers to an abstract class called `gameObj`.

And the 2nd and 3rd arguments to the function are the vector of pointers to the child class which inherits from `gameObj` as well.

I cannot for the love of my life, figure out the proper way to insert as a static casted pointer into the vector `mInstancedObjects`

Is this even the right way to go?

My guess is that I have to iterate through each element and manually static cast the obj followed by pushing the obj back into the `mInstancedObjects` vector. However this seems rather unwieldy and clunky since I would be making unnecessary loops.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There should be no need for a cast - a derived-class pointer can implicitly convert to a base-class pointer, and your use of `insert` should just work. Assuming the vectors are as you describe. Perhaps you could post their declarations, and the error message.

Comment: [Works](https://ideone.com/JGtNog) for me.

Comment: This is currently the error(s), i omitted the rest because they all of a similar effect.
`Error 1 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'c_Gate' to 'c_Object *' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0 600`

Comment: You're trying to convert an instance of `c_Gate` into a parent pointer.

Comment: That IS what I am actually trying to achieve, and hence the question on how to static_cast c_Gate elegantly and efficiently preferably without the use of a loop into its parent pointer.

Comment: Your question states that your other vectors contain *pointers* to the child class. Is this not the case?

Comment: Oh my, you are right. The vectors hold actual objects and not pointers. It seems like this was the problem all the while.

Answer (score 0):

A [test case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is worth a thousand words. Translating your description into compilable code:

```
#include <vector>

struct gameObj {};
struct gate : gameObj {};

int main() {
    std::vector<gameObj*> mInstancedObjects;
    std::vector<gate*> mGates;
    mInstancedObjects.insert(mInstancedObjects.end(), mGates.begin(), mGates.end());
}
```

This [works for me](http://ideone.com/XOoJvE), as it should since the conversion from a derived-class pointer to a base-class pointer can be done implicitly.

If you did need a static cast or other conversion, then you could avoid a loop with [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)

```
std::transform(mGates.begin(), mGates.end(),
               std::back_inserter(mInstancedObjects),
               [](gate * p) {return static_cast<gameObj*>(p);});
```

although a new-style for-loop might actually be nicer:

```
for (auto p : mGates) {
    mInstancedObjects.push_back(static_cast<gameObj*>(p));
}
```

But, unless you're doing something other than what you described, you shouldn't need any kind of explicit conversion, and the code you posted should just work.

Comment: The for-range loop seems like the goto way, however what could be the possible reasons why this would not work:

`gate myGate;`
`gameObj *mInstance = &myGate;`

It seems that my compiler prefers not to cast my child class into the parent class. Is there a specific operator overload that I am missing to allow implicit conversion?

Comment: @ChristopherLeong: That also [works for me](http://ideone.com/QOl73c). What error message do you get? Are you sure your types really do derive (publicly) from `gameObj`?

Comment: Ok, It seems that I have found the problem, my vector of child pointers was actually a vector of child objects and hence I got this error: `Error 1 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'c_Gate' to 'c_Object *' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0 600`

Answer (score 0):

So this was a huge mistake on my part, my assumption that the child game objects were stored a vector of pointers and treating it as such was the cause for the conversion errors.

Changing my vector from objects into a vector of pointer to objects was the solution.

Thank you everyone for your help.

">_<"